# Did OpenPOP.net with GMail attachments break recently?

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, email-attachments

I could swear this code was working few days ago. I'm using the SSL binaries from http://trixy.justinkbeck.com/2009/07/c-pop3-library-with-ssl-for-gmail.html

```
        POPClient client = new POPClient("pop.gmail.com", 995, "user@gmail.com", "qwerty", AuthenticationMethod.USERPASS, true);

        int unread = client.GetMessageCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < unread; i++)
        {
            Message m = client.GetMessage(i + 1, true);

            Console.WriteLine(m.Subject);

            if (m.HasAttachment)
            {
                Attachment a = m.GetAttachment(1);

                // Problem! HasAttachment flag is set, but there's no attachments in the collection!

                m.SaveAttachment(a, a.ContentFileName);
            }
        }
        client.QUIT();
```

But today, I can read the mail ok but the attachments are empty. I'm thinking the China fiasco caused them to change something. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenPop.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) now has SSL support directly in itself. It also had a lot of other upgrades. You should consider moving to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message m = client.GetMessage(i + 1, true);
```

got only the headers, and by changing it to

```
Message m = client.GetMessage(i + 1, false);
```

it works again.