# Looking for a pop3 reader class in C# with SSL support

Tags: c#, email, class, pop3

I was looking around and there is couple of projects but they all seem to be outdated, 
should i use those? or is there a new out the box pop3 class that I can't find in msdn.
anyhow i'm not doing a client that needs to send out so no SMTP is needed, more like a bot that sorts out the emails and reads them., any ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built one a few years back that's posted on code project and it is dated (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/NetPopMimeClient.aspx).  If you are interested I can send you a copy of the latest source code which was never posted to CP.

I ended up using Dart Mail as a replacement for the solution I developed posted on CP.  The main reason I ended up using Dart Mail is for the Mime Parsing facilities that it has which really ended up being the main problem with the solution I developed.  IIRC Dart Mail is pretty reasonable and may be worth a look if you need something that is robust.

Comment: is it www.dartmailindia.com/ or can you provide me a link for the Dart Mail you are talking about, i do need robust mime-type parsing.

Comment: Here is a direct URL to the product I am using. http://www.dart.com/ptmlnet.aspx.

Once you understand their object model it's really easy to parse complex MIME parts.  They offer a trial, definitely worth a try if you need something that works.  We use it for processing thousands of messages per day.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mail.dll POP3 client](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/). It supports SSL, is easy to use, and supports parsing complex MIME structures:

```
using(Pop3 pop3 = new Pop3())
{
    pop3.ConnectSSL("pop3.server.com");              
    pop3.Login("user", "password");

    foreach (string uid in pop3.GetAll())
    {
        IMail email = new MailBuilder()
            .CreateFromEml(pop3.GetMessageByUID(uid));
        Console.WriteLine(email.Subject);
    }
    pop3.Close(true);
}
```

Please note that this is a commercial product that I developed

You can download Mail.dll here:
http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/

Answer (score 1):

I discovered [OpenPOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098658/did-openpop-net-with-gmail-attachments-break-recently), which seems to be my library of choice at the moment for this very task.